# roslaunch using find packages on different machines looks for packages on local machine

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using roslaunch a lot to spawn different nodes on different machines I'm working on. Doing this using the launch syntax together with the machine tag works fine. However, I just found out that when using the $(find PkgName) syntax in a node which is spawned on a remote machine, ros actually starts looking for the package on my local laptop. I expected it to do that search on the remote machine however. Is this known (expected) behaviour or should I file a bug report for it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9948/roslaunch-using-find-packages-on-different-machines-looks-for-packages-on-local-machine/) by [Steven Bellens](https://answers.ros.org/users/55/steven-bellens/) on ROS Answers with karma: 735 on 2011-05-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is expected behavior: the roslaunch parameters are evaluated on the local computer, before being copied over SSH to a launch file on the remote machine (and thereafter executed).

---

Originally posted by [rbtying](https://answers.ros.org/users/285/rbtying/) with karma: 73 on 2011-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Steven Bellens](https://answers.ros.org/users/55/steven-bellens/) on 2011-05-12**:
OK. The packages I want to run on the remote machine are however not installed on my local pc. So I not only have to install those locally as well, the search doesn't make any sense here, as the actual execution will happen on the remote machine ?!